# Linking multiple hrefs to accordion and opening the corresponding section - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple hrefs that need to link to the proper accordion at the bottom of the page. The code I have now works, however I'm trying to minimize the amount of times I repeat functions as a coworker of mine points out that they are impractical. I have tried the location.hash solution, but it doesnt work for me. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```js
window.contentAssetInitFunctions.push(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start").click(function() {
      $('#startExchange, #startHeader').addClass('active');
      $('#packingSlip, #packingHeader').removeClass('active');
    });
    $("#pack").click(function() {
      $('#packingSlip, #packingHeader').addClass('active');
      $('#startExchange, #startHeader').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#startHeader" id="start" class="text-link">Learn How</a>
<a href="#packingHeader" id="pack" class="text-link">Learn How</a>

<a class="question" id="startHeader"> EXCHANGE</a>
<div class="answer" id="startExchange">
  content
</div>

<a class="question" id="packingHeader">HOW TO START AN EXCHANGE WITH A PACKING SLIP</a>
<div class="answer" id="packingSlip">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you control the html?  can you rename the id's in your hrefs/content?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each question/answer with a container tag (like an `article` or `div`), then you can target the whole section instead of having to pick out the question and answer with their custom ids.

Below you'll see I added a wrapper `article` tag with an id that describes the section.  Then the javascript removes all active tags, and then grabs the `id` from the `href`, finds that `article` and adds an active tag to that one.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".text-link").click(function () {
    let section = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    $('article .question, article .answer').removeClass('active')
    $(`#${section} .question, #${section} .answer`).addClass('active')
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#start" class="text-link">Learn How</a>
<a href="#packing" class="text-link">Learn How</a>

<article id="start">
  <a class="question"> EXCHANGE</a>
  <div class="answer">
    content
  </div>
</article>

<article id="packing">
  <a class="question">HOW TO START AN EXCHANGE WITH A PACKING SLIP</a>
  <div class="answer">
    content
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This only targets the header and doesnt make the header and the body active. Both startheader and startexchange need to be active and the same for the packing portion

Comment: Yep.  You are correct.  I've updated the solution to target both the question and answer portions when we add/remove the `active` class.